# How to stop a running script which calls a infinite loop

Tags: bash, performance-testing

I'm writing a bash script for kicking up an uncertain program. The run time of the program is unknown. The script will also kick up a while loop for using linux commands or perf to record something in a 1 second manner.

```
./my_app &
$i=1    
while true;
do
  perf stat -a -A -e writeback:writeback_dirty_page sleep $i >> out
done
```

How can I stop the while loop while my_app is finished? Thank you.

Comment: kill? either manual or from  another script http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?kill

Comment: check that `perf` doesn't offer option to run ever X seconds. Then you can do `perf .... &`; perfPid=$!; other stuff, kill $perfPid`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your while loop conditional on the process id of the app existing:

```
./my_app &
app_pid=$!
i=1
while ps -p $app_pid >/dev/null 2>&1
do 
  perf stat -a -A -e writeback:writeback_dirty_page sleep $i >> out
done
```

Comment: This method should be the easiest way to stop the while loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get the pid using

echo $!

then

kill

Answer (score 0):

you can send kill signal from `my_app` to the process that spawn `my_app`

Here is the real example

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

./my_app.sh $$ &

while [ 1 ]
do
    echo running....
    sleep 2
done
```

my_app.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10
kill -9 $1
```